# List all Computer Connection from Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I would like to know if there is a way to list the **Computer Connections** from Excel using VBA?

I was able to get all the **Workbook Connections** using this simple block of code:

```
Private Sub ListWorkBookConnections()
    Dim cnn As WorkbookConnection
    For Each cnn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        Debug.Print cnn.Name
    Next cnn
End Sub
```

Those are the connections that are specific to the Active workbook (the one currently opened) and that appear in the "*Connections in this Workbook*" section if you open the "*Existing Connection*" window of Excel (Data >> Existing Connection). See the Red sections in the Picture below :

[image: Existing Connections Pop Up]

What I would like to achieve is listing all the connection under the section "*Connection Files on this Computer*", in Blue on the image above.

I am using Excel 2007 on a Windows 7 computer.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer for your question, but I found your code very useful.  I changed your code so that I could delete active connections from a document that had hundreds of them.

```
    Private Sub DeleteWorkBookConnections()
      Dim cnn As WorkbookConnection
      For Each cnn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Item(1).Delete
      Next cnn
    End Sub
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Try it this way and let me know how it goes.

```
Dim conn As WorkbookConnection
For Each conn In ActiveWorkbook.Connections
  Debug.Print conn.Name
Next conn
```

Comment: I that's exactly what I did first. It just displays the connections in the Active Workbook. Check the code I wrote in my post. It's exactly what you proposed, the only difference being that you called your connection variable "conn"  instead of "cnn". Thanks for the help though!